# Create Google Developer Account For Google User Group

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to Create a Google Developer Account for a Google User Group Account ?

Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 1):

No, both are different from each other.

---

[Google Developer Account](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) (*Google Play Developer console*) is used for publishing Android Apps through Google Play Store by paying one time fee of $25 and on the other side [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com) is a place to create and participate in online forums and email based groups with a rich experience for community conversation.

Hope you get it!